# Nearest place within the latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I create simple API for IOS devices. In my project there is a table with the parties the latitude and longitude where they registered. The device gives me the latitude and longitude where it is and I have him return The list of parties that are closer to it within such km. How best to do this, please help and thanks.
I use clean PHP and mysql.

Comment: We are here to help with concrete programming questions. We are not here to "help" you build your system, or even design that system in the first place.

Comment: I did not ask for me to write code, I wanted to find a good practice to do this on PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a user defined function in mysql [e.g. distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)] which returns the distance of two points. Then you can query for other locations within a given radius of a given point, like in

```
select parties from mytable where distance(latitude,longitude,x,y) < 10
```

Do the processing in the database, not in the PHP client, for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you, I have not tested this solution, but I think this is exactly what I need